# Quick Explanation of SUBQUERY in NSPredicate Expression

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, subquery, nspredicate

There appears to be zero documentation about the SUBQUERY keyword from Apple and I can't find a simple explanation about it on SO or on Google. It's a conspiracy! ;)

*Please*, could someone from the inner-circle please just provide a quick explanation of its syntax so I can use it?

```
SUBQUERY(Bs, $x, $x IN %@)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This is what a subquery evaluates to.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:) (Found from [this mailing list thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/210757-nspredicate-for-any-match-based-on-two-properties-at-once.html), the #1 hit for “NSPredicate subquery” in Google.) That bit of documentation also explains how the predicate format string syntax relates to it.

Comment: Damn! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you know what letter to use?  Some places I see $x some places I see $s, some I see $a, and I can't see by context any diff between $x and $s.

Comment: @orange80: The variable name is your choice. See the documentation I linked to in my answer. If you know Python, it's like saying `[x for x in collection if (some condition involving x)]`. As far as I know, the variable name doesn't even have to be a single letter.

Comment: Just a note: at this moment THIS post is google's first hit for "nspresicate subquery" :) +1 for the link

Answer (score 44):

And for people who don't quite get what the documentation is saying, a `SUBQUERY` is essentially this:

```
SUBQUERY(collection, variableName, predicateFormat)
```

And could (simplistically) be implemented like this:

```
id resultingCollection = ...; //a new collection, either a mutable set or array
NSMutableDictionary * substitutions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat];
for (id variable in collection) {
  [substitutions setObject:variable forKey:variableName];
  NSPredicate * filter = [p predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:substitutions];
  if ([filter evaluateWithObject:collection] == YES) {
    [resultingCollection addObject:variable];
  }
}
return resultingCollection;
```

So in a nutshell, a `SUBQUERY` is basically taking a collection of objects and filtering out various objects based on the predicate expression of the `SUBQUERY`, and returning the resulting collection.  (And the predicate itself can contain other `SUBQUERY`s)

Example:

```
NSArray * arrayOfArrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:....],
                           nil];
NSPredicate * filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF, $a, $a.@count > 42)"];
NSArray * filtered = [arrayOfArrays filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
//"filtered" is an array of arrays
//the only arrays in "filtered" will have at least 42 elements each
```

Comment: Your NSPredicate won't compile:
caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(SELF, $a, $a.@count > 2)""

Comment: @cfisher Minor correction: That's a runtime error, not compilation error. (Not trying to be a jerk.)

Answer (score 1):

Subquery represents a predicate (third argument - `$x IN %@`) that is evaluated on all objects (second argument - `$x` - it's like a variable name in foreach) of a relationship (first argument - `Bs`). Similarly to regular query returns a list of objects.

I see in many places that people use `$x` almost dogmatically, but `$object` in `objects` relationship makes perfect sense as well (or `$city` in `cities`...) :)

I've written a blog post about `SUBQUERY` some time ago. You can check it [here](https://medium.com/@Czajnikowski/subquery-is-not-that-scary-3f95cb9e2d98).