# need help on a simple predicate to match any word in a string to a property

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Let's say i want to let user search for my objects using a name property of the objects.

I have no problem if the user only enters one word:
e.g: facial

My predicate will be:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", word];
```

But what if user enter more than one word separated by space?
I want to do sth like:

```
NSArray *words = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] ANY %@", words];
```

But it doesnt work. Any guidance?
Thanks!

Comment: i know my another option is to do sth like this:

        NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];        
        for(NSString *word in words)
        {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", word]; 
            [subPredicates addObject:predicate];
        }
        predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

but i hope to see if i can use the keyword ANY which i m not familiar with in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this (and I just learnt this myself as a result of your question) is to use subqueries. Check this [`SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810992/quick-explanation-of-subquery-in-nspredicate-expression) for more details. You can use subqueries in the following manner –

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(%@, $str, SELF CONTAINS[cd] $str).@count != 0", words];

NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

This seems to work as I've tested it myself but this could also be the arcane & obscure way that Dave has mentioned as it finds no mention in the Predicate Programming Guide.

The format for a `SUBQUERY` can be found [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery%3ausingIteratorVariable%3apredicate%3a). It's the same link that you will find in the question linked earlier.

Comment: Yeah, `SUBQUERY` is one of those weirder things of `NSPredicate`. Once you get how it works, you can't help but think of a way to use it in almost every situation.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned (correctly) in the comment, you can do this by building a compound predicate predicate, although you'll want to use `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`, and not the `and` variant.

That really is the best way to do this.  There are others, but they rely on more arcane and obscure uses of `NSPredicate`, and I really recommend going with the build-a-compound-predicate route.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation that this is also a good way to go. thanks