# CoreData NSPredicate with relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have following CoreData objects Model

[image]

Now I am having issue in making a predicate with following conditions.

Fetch all those `DBOpportunity` WHERE

DBOpportunity.stateCode == 1

AND

DBOpportunity.invoiceDate >= GIVEN_DATE

AND

DBOpportunityLines.crmAccept == 1 OR DBOpportunityLines.crmAccept == 3

I have tried lots of examples and programming guide by the [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3) but can't able to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opportunitylines` is a *to-many* relationship, so there are multiple DBOpportunityLines objects for one DBOpportunity object. Assuming that the last condition

> DBOpportunityLines.crmAccept == 1 OR DBOpportunityLines.crmAccept == 3

should hold for *any* of the related objects, you need a SUBQUERY:

```
NSDate *givenDate = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stateCode == 1 AND invoiceDate >= %@ "
    "AND SUBQUERY(opportunitylines, $x, $x.crmAccept == 1 OR $x.crmAccept == 3).@count > 0",
    givenDate];
```

*Remark:* Unfortunately, the usage of SUBQUERY in predicates is poorly documented. There is [one example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-init) in the NSExpression class reference. See also [Quick Explanation of SUBQUERY in NSPredicate Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810992/quick-explanation-of-subquery-in-nspredicate-expression).

Comment: @Marting thanx alot, it was excellent solution. Can you guide me in slight modificaiton of above sub query. I just want to keep all conditions as such with one extra condition. Currently opportunitylines.crmAccept should be 1 or 3 i want to also include if there is no opportunitylines with opportunity entity.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH: Probably something like `"stateCode == 1 AND invoiceDate >= %@ AND (SUBQUERY(opportunitylines, $x, $x.crmAccept == 1 OR $x.crmAccept == 3).@count > 0 OR opportunitylines.@count == 0)"`.

Comment: Thanx during hit and trial i did that :)

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your predicate is `A && B && (C || D)`

Setup your predicates

```
NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stateCode == %d", value];
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"invoiceDate >=  %@", givenDate];
```

Similar do the cPredicate and dPredicate. Then first combine c and d with OR

```
NSArray *cdPredicateArray = @[cPredicate, dPredicate];
NSPredicate *cdPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:cdPredicateArray];
```

and then all of them with AND

```
NSArray *allPredicateArray = @[aPredicate, bPredicate, cdPredicate];
NSPredicate *allPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:allPredicateArray];
```

If I misunderstood your question and your structure is `A && B && C || D` Then you have to combine A, B and C first (with AND) and then combine that result with D (with OR).

Comment: Note that the entity name is not part of the predicate, so the first one would be just `... "stateCode == %d", value]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also fetch your `opportunityLines` and then get the parent entities like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"opportunityLines" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSDate *yourDate = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(crmAccept==1 OR crmaccept==3) AND opportunity.stateCode==1 AND opportunity.invoiceDate>=%@", yourDate];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

//So here you have your array of opportunitylines
NSArray *opportunityLines = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

//And this is how you get your opportunity objects
NSArray *opportunities = [opportunityLines valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.opportunity"];
```