# How to define temporary variable inside NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, subquery, nspredicate

I need a predicate almost like this:

```
let frOU = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "OU")
frOU.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "IN o.ous.recordName = %@ AND IN o.ous.checkedOut = true", "123")
```

but it would be important that the two conditions match to the same `OU` managed object. How can I write it?

someting like `"$(o.ous) IN ($0.recordName = %@ AND $0.checkedOut = true)"` but with right syntacs, is it possible with core data?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a SUBQUERY, for example

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(o.ous, $x, $x.recordName = %@ AND $x.checkedOut = true).@count > 0", "123")
```

finds all "OU" objects which are related to an "O" object which is related to any
"OU" object with the given record name and checked-out value.

Comment: @János: The only Apple documentation that I know of is hidden in the NSExpression Class Reference. There are also some SO answers demonstrating the use or SUBQUERY. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810992/quick-explanation-of-subquery-in-nspredicate-expression might also be useful.