# Count query Core Data predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicates

i have a entity called schedule that has many alarms (other entity), i want to get only schedules that have less then 30 future alarms. Searching all around i get that query that not works /:

```
 let predicateFutureAlarms = NSPredicate(format: "(alarms.date > %@).@count < 30", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

(on running time a (lldb) appears on console and appoints to the initialization of that variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two problems:

- `"(alarms.date > %@).@count < 30"` is not a valid predicate syntax.
- The `%@` placeholder expects an *object*, but `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` is a floating point *number*.

I cannot test it currently, but something like this should work:

```
let now = NSDate()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(alarms, $a, $a.date > %@).@count < 30", now)
```

For each `Schedule` object, the `SUBQUERY(...)` evaluates to all related `alarms` objects which have
a `date` which is greater than `now`.

See ["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for a general description of the predicate
syntax. The "SUBQUERY" expression is poorly documented,
compare the [`NSExpression` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/) or [Quick Explanation of SUBQUERY in NSPredicate Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810992/quick-explanation-of-subquery-in-nspredicate-expression).

Comment: Thanks!!!, it works, in this case "date" is actually a float, so i change %@ to %f too.

Comment: @user1779394: You are welcome! – I had assumed that `date` is a "Date" attribute (which might be more appropriate).