# Fetch objects from Core Data where a filtered relationship is empty

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Let's say I've got `Employee` objects which have 1-to-many relationship to `WorkShift` objects called `shifts`. `WorkShift` has a `startDate` property which marks when that shift began.

I want to fetch all of the employees that did NOT start working between two dates, i.e. if an `Employee` has 0 `WorkShift` records with `startDate` between A and B dates, then I want to include that `Employee` in my result set.

If I just needed to find employees where `shifts` was completely empty, I believe I could just use a predicate of `shifts.@count = 0`, but I need to filter `shifts` based on `startDate` and THEN check if the `@count = 0`, but I have no idea how to do that in a predicate.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out based on some other posts talking about [SUBQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810992/quick-explanation-of-subquery-in-nspredicate-expression)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"SUBQUERY(shifts, $x, %@ <= $x.startDate and $x.startDate <= %@).@count == 0",
    beginningOfDateRange, endingOfDateRange);
```

The `SUBQUERY` function takes the relationship (collection) in question as the first parameter. The second parameter is just a variable definition that says I'm going to use `$x` to refer to each of the items within the relationship collection when I build my conditional in the third parameter. Then, of course, the 3rd parameter is the filter I'm using to reduce the collection. I'm looking for `WorkShift` records with `startDate` between my two dates.. but I want all of the `Employees` that don't have any, so I use the subquery to find all of the `WorkShift` records in that range and then I check for the `.@count == 0` to make sure there aren't any in that range.

Kind of brain-twisty, but it works like a charm.